# how to style xml tag attribute with css

Tags: html, css, xml, attributes

I'm trying to give style to a xml file that is displayed as a page, so far I could manage to give style to only the "start" attribute of the tag, but I need to style two more attributes: "end" and "n".

Currently I have:

**css**:

```
#mtxt tok { font-size: 14pt; }
#mtxt u { display: block; text-decoration: none; margin-bottom: 10px; }
#mtxt u:before { content: attr(start); color: #999900; padding-right: 30px; font-size: 9pt; }
#mtxt l { display: block; }
```

**xml**:

```
<u n="1" start="00:00:23,912" end="00:00:26,540" id="u-1">
<tok id="w-1">Now we're reading from the letter of st. Paul</tok>
</u>
```

**visualization**: (kind of, for you to see more or less the result)

*00:00:23,912* : **Now we're reading from the letter of st. Paul**

**The visualization I'm trying to get is next one:**

**1)** *00:00:23,912 - 00:00:26,540* : **Now we're reading from the letter of st. Paul**

Any Suggestions... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgg1Lapo/)

**CSS**

```
u:before {
  content: attr(n) ') ' attr(start) ' - ' attr(end);
  color: #999900;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

You can have multiple `attr()` inside. Just add a space inbetween. To add text, just wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much I have tried similar things, but not this, thanks again.